# Unique id for any kind of callable object in C++17

Tags: c++, hash, functional-programming, c++17, template-meta-programming

In one part of my code, I have an abstract function type `Function` which represents any kind of callable and which can be stored in a heterogeneous container, e.g. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Function>>`:

```cpp
#include <any>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

class Function
{
public:
    Function(std::string name)
     : m_name(name)
    {}

    virtual ~Function(){}

    std::string name() {
        return m_name;
    }
    
    template <typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
         // delegate to invoke, implementation not relevant for question
    }
private:
    std::string m_name;
    // the following is also simplified for the sake of brevity
    virtual std::any invoke(std::initializer_list<std::any> const& args) const = 0;
};

template <typename F>
class FunctionImpl : public Function
{
public:
    FunctionImpl(F const& f, std::string name)
     : Function(name)
     , function(f)
    {}

private:
    std::any invoke(std::initializer_list<std::any> const& args) const override
    {
        // implementation not relevant for question
        return std::any();
    }

    F function;
};

using FPointer = std::unique_ptr<Function>;

template <typename F>
FPointer make_function(F const& f, std::string name)
{
    return std::make_unique<FunctionImpl<F>>(f, name);
}
```

Now I want to add a function

```cpp
using FContainer = std::vector<FPointer>;

template <typename F>
bool contains(FContainer const& vec, F const& f)
{
    // ?????
}
```

which returns true, if the function passed as argument in contained in the container, and false otherwise *(and probably in a follow-up step a function that returns a reference to the element in the container, if it is contained)*. **How would I write this kind of function? What are my options?**

```cpp
void bar(){}
void foo(){}

struct AClass {
    void MemberFunction1(){}
    void MemberFunction2(){}
};

struct ACallableClass
{
    void operator()(){}
};

int main()
{
    FContainer v;

    // function pointer
    v.push_back( 
        make_function(
            &foo,
            "foo"
        )
    );

    // std::function
    v.push_back( 
        make_function(
            std::function<void()>(&foo),
            "foo"
        )
    );

    // member function
    v.push_back( 
        make_function(
            &AClass::MemberFunction1,
            "AClass::MemberFunction1"
        )
    );

    // callable
    v.push_back(
        make_function(
            ACallableClass(),
            "CallableClass"
        )
    );

    // lambda
    v.push_back( 
        make_function(
            [](){},
            "empty lambda"
        )
    );

    assert(contains(v, &foo));
    assert(contains(v, std::function<void()>(&foo)));
    assert(contains(v, &AClass::MemberFunction1));
    assert(!contains(v, [](){})); // every lambda is different

    assert(!contains(v, &bar));
    assert(!contains(v, std::function<void()>(&bar)));
    assert(!contains(v, &AClass::MemberFunction2));

    return 0;
}
```

The best solution I could come up with so far was to write a function template

```cpp
template <typename F> size_t id(F&& id);
```

that gives a unique id to any kind of callable. Then `Function` could get a new virtual `size_t id() const = 0` method, which would be overwritten by `Function<F>`. The latter delegates to the free function template. With this, I could compare ids in `contains`.

I tried implementing the function template using `std::hash` with function pointers, but I got stuck at hashing member function pointers, callable classes and lambdas. Here is my latest approach: https://godbolt.org/z/zx4jnYbeG.

Sorry for the rather lengthy question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### EDIT 1:

I can live without `std::function` support. I would like to support lambdas in principle, but I can live with `contains` always returning false for lambdas, which makes sense to me. I do want the code to work with function pointers, callable classes and member functions.

### EDIT 2:

Here is a working solution based on the suggestions in xryl669s answer: https://godbolt.org/z/vYGesEsKa. `std::function<F>` and `F` get the same id, but I suppose this actually make sense, since they are basically equivalent.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)? [`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) is comparable and hashable already.

Comment: @Useless Thought of something alike as well – though that relies on the type only and wouldn't distinguish different instances of the same type. Might or might not be an issue – QA: please clarify...

Comment: Not sure why you would need this at all. What are you intending to solve with? Possibly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: Taking the pointer to a member function without capturing the instance is very strange, not to say the less. How can one know if it need an instance of a specific class when invoking ?

Comment: Hashing alone is usually not sufficient, unless you invent a way to crate a perfect hash for your case, because of possible collisions. The proper way would be delegate job to the `operator==` of stored callable.

Comment: @xryl669 OP mentions that he uses `invoke` under the hood. With `invoke` you can threat member functions as normal functions with reference to object as additional first argument `obj.*mptr(args...)` → `invoke(mptr, obj, args...)`

Comment: Wouldn't typeid return the same id for two different functions with the same signature? https://godbolt.org/z/xMbqKcfKj

Comment: Lie Revolver_Ocelot said, with std::invoke I don't have to capture the instance for the member function.

Comment: @Aconcagua, might be an XY-Problem, I am not sure. My code basically models a minimalistic dynamically typed sublanguage in C++ using a reflection system. Reflected types and functions are stored in heterogeneous containers. Now given a new function or an instance of any type, I would like to find out if it has previously been registered in the reflection system by searching the corresponding container.

Comment: Are you registering types or objects?

Comment: types, or rather, objects describing the types. But I don't have an issue with the type registry, I have an issue with the function registry, because it doesn't suffice to describe the type of the function, because two distinct functions with the same signature could have the same type. So I need to deal with types and functions differently, hence the approach from the question.

Comment: Hm. There is a contradiction right here. If you are registering types, why do you care about different values having the same type? It looks like you want to register values, and that's a problem, because in general the only unique identifier of the value is the value itself

Comment: Ah sorry, I think there is a misunderstanding: I am distinguishing "registering types" and "registering functions" in the reflection system. So the reflection system has two seperate subsystems, one for types and one for funtions - precisely because for the first, I don't care about different values having the same entry and for the latter I do care. This question concerns only the function registry, I just wanted to add more context with my previous comment.

Comment: For the types you can just use type_info as the key. For the functions it's a problem. You can't in general get a unique ID of an arbitrary function object (or any other arbitrary object). But why do you need that? Can you compare arbitrary function values in your language? That would be a very unusual language feature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248121/discussion-between-joergbrech-and-n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `unordered_map` and not a `vector` to store your functions.
The key can be derived from the name (probably better anyway), or from the address of the function, but in that case, you'll have an issue with everything that's not a real function (like a method, a std::function<> instance, a lambda, ...)

But since you probably have an issue already with your `make_function` for methods (you don't capture the instance), you can probably make a specialization for that case using a lambda or a template trampoline and use that address instead.

Another issue to account for is:

1. std::function<>(&foo) != std::function<>(&foo) (you have 2 instances, they are 2 different objects)
2. Similarly for lambda functions, two different instance containing the same lambda body won't match anyway.
3. Compiler is allowed to generate copies of functions if it has all the code for them and it's doing so unless you build with `-Os` or use external linkage for your functions

So, unless you fallback to a unique identifier that *you* assign to your Function, you can't assert that a function is identical to another based on the function's body or some instance.

Example (working) godbolt for the specialized template approach: https://godbolt.org/z/8sP5MfG6r

Please notice that you can't store a `&foo` and `std::function<>(&foo)` in the container in this approach if using the `std::function<>::target()` as the key, they'll point to the same function and thus will be overwritten or not inserted since they already exist, but that's probably a good thing for your application it seems.

If you don't care about UB, you can use this version: https://godbolt.org/z/9GoEWMnMb that's `reinterpret_cast`'ing the function's pointer (and pointer to method too) to use as the hash's key in the map. That's not clean, but since we don't use the result of the cast to call the function, it shouldn't bother much.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't believe I have an issue with methods if I can work with std::invoke. I can't use the name as key, because the whole point of the `contains` function is that I pass any type of callable and not an instance of `Function`. So I am stuck with the problem of pointer to methods (among others). Finally, what do you mean by a template trampoline?

Comment: Note that you can cast pointers to member functions to pointers to another type – though using the cast pointer to call the pointee would yield UB, meaning that you need to cast back before doing so.

Comment: Can you though? https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#cant-cvt-memfnptr-to-voidptr. If I could, I wouldn't mind the UB because I don't intend to call the pointee but just use the pointer to generate a unique id. EDIT: I just tested it on godbolt, you can't static_cast, but you can implicit cast and get a warning from gcc. I am not super comfortable with it...

Comment: What I mean by a trampoline is that you make a specialization for `FunctionImpl<std::function<T>>` and capture the `target()` for deducing the `id` not the instance of the `std::function` itself.

Comment: Ah ok, gotcha. Though your godbolt example still fails on the first std::function assert, right? BTW, I can live without std::functions. Function pointers, member function pointers and callable classes would be cool.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong link. I've edited the answer with the right link, every assert passes.

Comment: Actually, it segfaults before the first assert (`-fsanitize=adress`)

Comment: Ok, fixed the issue, and it's working with all your cases including `std::function`. I had to store the address of the functions in variable because else the compiler is generating different values each time. It shouldn't happen if the function had external linkage.

Comment: Ah nice! We are getting there, thanks a lot! Unfortunately, storing the addresses of the functions is not an option for me. The problem seems to be that you form pointers to (member) function pointers. I suppose this can be caught with `if constexpr`, and `std::is_pointer` and `std::is_member_function_pointer`... I will experiment a bit later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248111/discussion-between-xryl669-and-joergbrech).