# Are the addresses of the call operators of two lambdas guaranteed to be distinct?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda

This is a follow-up of this SO question: [Unique id for any kind of callable object in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73744246/unique-id-for-any-kind-of-callable-object-in-c17). In essence, I want to be able to assign a unique id to any function, similar to `std::type_index`. The basic idea behind the accepted answer in the above question is to use the address of the function as an id. For functors or lambdas of type `X`, the address of `X::operator()` is used.

The big issue with this solution is that it builds on UB: I need to `reinterpret_cast` any function pointer to an integral type which I use as id, e.g. `std::uintptr_t`. I figured, as long as I do not use this reinterpeted value to access the function pointer, I am fine.

The code works as expected with one small exception: I expect the ids of two lambdas to be different, because each lambda has its own type and thus its own call operator.

This expectation is met in all my tests on gcc 7 and 12, clang 10 and 14 and msvc 2017 and 2022, except for MSVC release builds.

To reproduce:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Lambda>
std::uintptr_t address_of_call_operator(Lambda&&){
    return []<typename Op>(Op const& pointer_to_op){ 
        return reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t&>(const_cast<Op&>(pointer_to_op));
    }(&Lambda::operator());
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::hex << address_of_call_operator([]{}) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::hex << address_of_call_operator([]{}) << "\n";
}
```

Building with `cl main.cpp /std:c++20` gives me different addresses as expected:

```
7ff64cec1230
7ff64cec1240
```

Building with `cl main.cpp /std:c++20 /O2` gives me the same address:

```
7ff790a32b80
7ff790a32b80
```

This brings me to my questions:

- It is common to rely on the fact that two lambdas have distinct types. Can I not rely on the address of the call operator of two lambdas to be different?
- Is there an alternative I can use to get a unique id from a function (pointer) that does not rely on UB or at least works on all major platforms?

Comment: note that lambdas can have templated `operator()`

Comment: why not use `std::type_index` of the lambdas type? Yes, two lambda expressions are guaranteed to be of different type

Comment: [COMDAT folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/opt-optimizations?view=msvc-170) breaks your assumption.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai because then I get the same id for two different functions (not lambdas) of the same signature: E.g. `double add(double, double)` and `double multiply(double, double)` would get the same id. And I am fine with only supporting non-templated lambdas and functors without overloaded call operators. I know about this restriction.

Comment: @Botje, thanks, I didn't know about COMDAT folding. Is it legal in this case? Is MSVC right to do it? The other compilers don't seem to do it.

Comment: sorry, I dont completely understand. You anyhow have to make the distinction between types with `operator()` and bare functions, for naked functions you can use the address while for functors the `type_index`. Perhaps you want to use the same for both, ok ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Ah I see, I think I didn't understand you correctly. Yes, that may be a solution: For anything that has a call operator I use the `type_index` (since I don't support templated or overloaded call operators anyway). For everything else I use the function pointer, right? This might be a workaround for me, thanks! The main question still remains though.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168924/gcc-clang-merging-functions-with-identical-instructions-comdat-folding) seems like a good starting point for answering your questions. Look at [this linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188612/is-an-implementation-allowed-to-site-two-identical-function-definitions-at-the-s) too

Comment: exactly. And yes, the actual question still remains, but I think I now understood what you want to do

Comment: I just found a related (dupe?) question thanks to @Botjes links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176320/why-are-member-function-pointers-behaving-so-weirdly-in-visual-c. The answer makes no comment on wether the COMDAT folding is legal or not.

Comment: also this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533740/do-distinct-functions-have-distinct-addresses

Comment: Have you checked if `reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t&>` is legal as a _"pointer-to-member"_ is not the same as a  _"pointer"_ and my first reading of [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) suggests this not legal use.

Comment: @RichardCritten I know it's UB. But still it is observable that the call operators of two distinct lambdas get the same address due to COMDAT folding.

Comment: I don't think that trying to reason about a program with UB is useful.

Comment: @RichardCritten Knowing what I know now I could rephrase the question without relying on UB. But I don't see the point as the question was already (rightfully) marked as a duplicate.

Comment: My think was - if the difference is only observable when invoking UB and not observable without UB.  Then under the _"as-if-rule"_ the compiler can do what it likes as we cannot observe the difference.

Comment: @joergbrech It is not UB. It is ill-formed. The compiler ought to complain about it. If it doesn't then it is non-conforming. A pointer-to-member can't be cast to an integral type. It isn't even conditionally-supported. What you are seeing here is completely MSVC-specific non-conforming behavior which I would expect to fail with `/permissive-`.

Comment: @joergbrech As far as I remember MSVC's implementation of member pointers is in general non-conforming.